# Join overlaping sf objects using specific attribute condition

Tags: r, dataframe, join, spatial, r-sf

I have multiple dataframes (`sf` objects). Each dataframe contains a `geometry`, `name` and `probability` column. They all have the same extents, but only overlap in some regions.

Here is some example data using two dataframes:

```
nc<-st_read(
  system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg",
              package="sf"),
  quiet=TRUE)
a<-nc %>%
  select(c('geom')) %>%
  slice(1:60) %>%
  mutate(probability=runif(n=60,
                    min=1,
                    max=100)) %>%
  mutate(name='A')
b<-nc %>%
  select(c('geom')) %>%
  slice(50:100) %>%
  mutate(probability=runif(n=51,
                    min=1,
                    max=100)) %>%
  mutate(name='B')
```

I would like to `merge`/`join` these two dataframes (`a` and `b`), but in the regions where they overlap, I would like to only keep the `name` where the `probability` is highest. The new dataframe should contain the `name` and `probability`.

How would I start with such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases you can handle sf objects as regular data.frames / tibbles with added benefits of spatial joins. Following example uses `st_equals` to limit matches to only those that originate from `nc[50:60,]` (neighbouring polygons in *nc* overlap, so the number of matches with `st_intersects` would be higher), for your real data you probably want to use something else (like default `st_intersects`), check `?st_join` for alternatives.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# by default st_join uses st_intersects predicate & left_join
# switching to st_equals & inner join
ab <- st_join(a, b, join = st_equals, suffix = c("_a", "_b"), left = F) %>%
  mutate(
    name = if_else(probability_a > probability_b, name_a, name_b),
    probability = pmax(probability_a, probability_b)
    # uncomment to only keep unused columns
    # , .keep = "unused"
  )

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = a,  aes(alpha = probability), color = "gray80", fill = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = b,  aes(alpha = probability), color = "gray80", fill = "green") +
  geom_sf(data = ab, aes(alpha = probability), color = "gray80", fill = "blue") +
  geom_sf_label(data = ab, aes(label = name), alpha = .5) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]
Resulting sf:

```r
ab
#> Simple feature collection with 11 features and 6 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -83.9547 ymin: 35.18983 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.22926
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> First 10 features:
#>    probability_a name_a probability_b name_b                           geom
#> 50     69.580424      A     91.374717      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.29824 3...
#> 51     48.284343      A     30.066734      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.47388 3...
#> 52     86.259738      A     46.447507      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.96143 3...
#> 53     44.371614      A     33.907073      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.2581 35...
#> 54     25.234930      A     65.436176      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.53874 3...
#> 55      7.997226      A     26.543661      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.74389 3...
#> 56     10.847150      A     48.375980      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.78317 3...
#> 57     32.310899      A     76.864756      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.10377 3...
#> 58     52.344792      A      9.340445      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-83.33182 3...
#> 59     66.538503      A     87.656812      B MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.80518 3...
#>    name probability
#> 50    B    91.37472
#> 51    A    48.28434
#> 52    A    86.25974
#> 53    A    44.37161
#> 54    B    65.43618
#> 55    B    26.54366
#> 56    B    48.37598
#> 57    B    76.86476
#> 58    A    52.34479
#> 59    B    87.65681
```

Input:

```r
set.seed(1)
nc <- st_read(
  system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg",
    package = "sf"
  ),
  quiet = TRUE
)
a <- nc %>%
  select(c("geom")) %>%
  slice(1:60) %>%
  mutate(probability = runif(
    n = 60,
    min = 1,
    max = 100
  )) %>%
  mutate(name = "A")
b <- nc %>%
  select(c("geom")) %>%
  slice(50:100) %>%
  mutate(probability = runif(
    n = 51,
    min = 1,
    max = 100
  )) %>%
  mutate(name = "B")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

#### Joining more than 2 sf objects

A somewhat silly example just to show how one could join multiple sf objects with reduce(), pivot from wide to long, group by "something" and then pick rows with max probabilities from each group. As-is it's probably not too practical. Following just extends previous code.

```r
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

# add c and d
c <- nc %>%
  select(c("geom")) %>%  slice(45:65) %>%
  mutate(probability = runif(n = 21, min = 1,max = 100)) %>%
  mutate(name = "C")

d <- nc %>%
  select(c("geom")) %>%  slice(40:70) %>%
  mutate(probability = runif(n = 31, min = 1,max = 100)) %>%
  mutate(name = "D")

# collect sf objects into list
abcd <- list("a" = a,
             "b" = b,
             "c" = c,
             "d" = d) 

abcd_ijoin <- abcd %>% 
  # rename columns in each sf, skip geom col
  imap(function(sf_, name_) sf_ %>% rename_with(~ paste(.x, name_, sep = '_'), -geom)) %>% 
  # $a
  #                              geom probability_a name_a
  # 1  MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...     27.285358      A
  # ...
  
  # "Reduce a list to a single value by iteratively applying a binary function"
  # basically st_join(a,b) %>% st_join(c) %>% st_join(d)
  # or st_join(st_join(st_join(a,b),c),d)
  # join = st_equals, left = F are passed to each st_join() call,
  # each call adds 2 columns
  reduce(st_join, join = st_equals, left = F) %>% 
  #    probability_a name_a probability_b name_b probability_c name_c probability_d name_d                           geom
  # 50     69.580424      A     91.374717      B      63.51060      C      13.78653      D MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.29824 3...
  # 51     48.284343      A     30.066734      B      39.61781      C      26.38039      D MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.47388 3...  

  # remove name_* columns
  select(!starts_with("name")) %>% 
  #    probability_a probability_b probability_c probability_d                           geom
  # 50     69.580424     91.374717      63.51060      13.78653 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.29824 3...
  # 51     48.284343     30.066734      39.61781      26.38039 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.47388 3...  

  # pivot from wide to long format, 
  # probability_a, probability_b, .. values are collected into single "probability" column and
  # name-part(a,b,c,..) of column name ends up in "name" column
  pivot_longer(starts_with("probability"), names_pattern = "probability_(.*)", values_to = "probability") %>% 
  # A tibble: 44 × 3
  #                                                   geom name  probability
  #                                     <MULTIPOLYGON [°]> <chr>       <dbl>
  # 1 (((-80.29824 35.4949, -80.72652 35.50757, -80.766... a            69.6
  # 2 (((-80.29824 35.4949, -80.72652 35.50757, -80.766... b            91.4

  # group by some feature (by geom only works because objects were joined with st_equals)
  # and get row with max probabilty from each group
  group_by(geom) %>% 
  slice_max(probability) %>% 
  ungroup()
  # A tibble: 11 × 3
  #                                                   geom name  probability
  #                                     <MULTIPOLYGON [°]> <chr>       <dbl>
  # 1 (((-80.29824 35.4949, -80.72652 35.50757, -80.766... b            91.4
  # 2 (((-77.47388 35.42153, -77.50456 35.48483, -77.50... a            48.3

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = bind_rows(abcd), color = "gray80", alpha = .1) +
  geom_sf(data = abcd_ijoin, aes(fill = name, alpha = probability), color = "gray80") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @margusl. I am still learning all the sf functions. Your input is very helpful and truly appreciate it.

Comment: how would your code work if you wanted to compare the probability between three dataframes? st_join only allows for 2 objects.

Comment: Added some convoluted purrr-based code  just to show how this might be targeted (objects in list, join through reduce ). Though this really boils down to your real data. It's quite likely that you can't use that exact approach. And you might be not that interested in just dealing with those fixed polygons but instead, you want to study geometric intersections & diffs of partially overlapping shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by `@margusl`'s answer, I ended up using this code to answer my question. I leave the code here for someone who might find it useful.

```
# Merge into one file
abcd<-rbind(a,b,c,d)

# Spatial selection
  abcd<-abcd %>%
    pivot_longer(prob) %>%
    group_by(geometry) %>%
    slice_max(value) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(prob=value) %>%
    select(c(prob,name,geometry))
```